# 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.0.0.0

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-standard-2.1

I'm using `netstandard2.1` library in my `netcoreapp3.0` web application. When adding my service in `Startup`, I'm getting the below error:

> 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.0.0.0

I'm also using some features from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` 2.2.0 package in my class library.

Here is my library `.csproj`,

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is my `ServiceExtensions` class from my library,

```cs
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
    public static IMvcBuilder AddMyLibrary(this IMvcBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        builder.AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });
        builder.Services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureLibraryOptions>();

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Here is my `ConfigureLibraryOptions` class,

```cs
public class ConfigureLibraryOptions : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomBinderProvider());
    }
}
```

Here is the `ConfigureServices` from `Startup`,

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMyLibrary();
```

Please help on why I'm getting this error and assist on how to solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the error is because `MvcJsonOptions` was removed in .NET Core 3.0; you can read more about the breaking changes [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/325).

Comment: This means I cannot use `netstandard2.1` class library with reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` 2.2.0 in `netcoreapp3.0`? Instead I should change the `netstandard2.1` to `netcoreapp3.0` and add a `FrameworkReference` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`?

Answer (score 116):

I'm not sure if this solves OP's problem, but this error also occurs when you use Swashbuckle 4 in .Net Core 3.  The solution is to use Swashbuckle 5.
(use command `install-package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`) to have in .csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
```

Then you'll need to upgrade it in Startup.cs.  Generally that involves prefixing classes that don't compile with `OpenApi` e.g.

`options.SwaggerDoc("v1" new Info ...`

becomes

`options.SwaggerDoc("v1", OpenApiInfo`

Also `OpenApiSecurityScheme` becomes `ApiKeyScheme`

See also docs at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Comment: The property `Version` for the object `OpenApiInfo` states that it is REQUIRED to be defined. If I skip defining it, everything works, other than not having 2 special labels printed next to my application's name in the UI generated by the swagger (One contains the version we've omitted, the other `OAS3`. What does it mean?). Why is it required, and what do we signify with it? In the docs you linked, it's defined as `v1`. Should it stay like that, or is that a mere example -- we should rather store **our** application's version there instead. It can be anything, such as `0.0.1a-ffg`

Comment: @Support Monica - SpiritBob: it goes into the info object of the swagger.json file.  It's required because it's required by the spec. I've never had a need to change it from "v1".  You can read more about it in the official docs here: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#info-object

Comment: Thank you, this helped me during our upgrade process

Answer (score 20):

netstandard2.1 to netcoreapp3.0
MvcJsonOptions -> MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            //MVC
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
            }).AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.PostConfigure<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new MyCustomContractResolver()
                {
                    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
                };
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
}
```

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved IF you also include the fact that we will need to install the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson or this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely with the incompatible nuget packages for .net core 3.1 above. Take a look at your packages and eventually upgrade to compatible version of core 3.1. That should really fix the issue I had one with Automapper and others had with Swagger.

If you are using AutoMapper you should upgrade to 7.0.0

See https://medium.com/@nicky2983/how-to-using-automapper-on-asp-net-core-3-0-via-dependencyinjection-a5d25bd33e5b

Answer (score 1):

When you config "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore", needed for configuring ApiKeyScheme become to OpenApiSecurityScheme it is changing the scheme from

```
 c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new ApiKeyScheme { In = "header", Description = 
 "Please enter JWT with Bearer into field", Name = "Authorization", Type = "apiKey" 
 });
 c.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> {
 { "Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>() }, });
```

To

```
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Description =
        "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 12345abcdef\"",
    Name = "Authorization",
    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
    Scheme = "Bearer"
});

c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
{
    {
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Reference = new OpenApiReference
            {
                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                Id = "Bearer"
            },
            Scheme = "oauth2",
            Name = "Bearer",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,

        },
        new List<string>()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to add `services.AddControllers()` as described under https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1961#issuecomment-515631411.