# Cannot run (or host) application migrated from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 3.0. and changing the port

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis-express

I'm trying to migrate my app from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET Core 3.0. I've seen Microsoft document regarding this kind of migration, but I've also seen 2 or 3 tutorials which are way shorter than it and are enough to migrate the app.

I started with changing the `<TargetFramework>` from `netcoreapp2.1` to `netcoreapp3.0`. As expected, it caused a few issues regarding all the packages, but I resolved it by upgrading them or changing deprecated methods to another.

Now the things are getting weird. I tried to run the application, but got following error:

> Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.0.0.0

OK, happens, not the first time I encounter some issue during this migration and probably not last. According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362757/could-not-load-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcjsonoptions-from-assembly-mi) found on Stack, it is because MvcJsonOptions has been removed in .NET Core 3.0. I tried to search for it in my application, but couldn't find any code. Guess it's some internal stuff then. Anyway, most upvoted solution was to update Swashbuckle to version 5.0, so I did. And here comes my troubles:

1. When I try to run the application, I get "Failed to bind to address http://localhost:5000". This is strange, because few minutes before I've just run this app but in .NET Core 2.1 and it worked perfectly fine. I have checked ports using netstat and port 5000 isn't used by anything. I'm using IIS Express.
2. When I change the host, I simply cannot run the application. It just loads forever. I've set some breakpoints, but everything looks fine - it just goes through all the code in the `Startup.cs`, but then it loads infinitely. What seems to be worse, I tried to change the port on another copy of my app, before migrating it to .NET Core 3.0 and it works perfectly fine. Just changed the numbers in `appsettings.json` and `launchsettings.json` and it works.

So in summary, my application fails to bind to my standard address after migrating it to .NET Core 3.0 and when I change it, something very strange is happening and it loads infinitely. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

MvcJsonOptions has been removed in .net core 3.0. Try installing Newtonsoft.Json NuGet Package and build your project.