# Getting error with IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I just upgraded my .NETCore 2.2 api application to 3.1. The solution was working fine in 2.2 version.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MvcJsonOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I googled it and spent almost a day to figure it out but could not found any relevant solution. What options should I use instead of `IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>` in .Net Core 3.1. Could someone please help me with this?

```
         public JsonDeserialiser(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> options) : this(options.Value.SerializerSettings)
        {

        }
```

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362757/could-not-load-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcjsonoptions-from-assembly-mi) may helpful.

Comment: Hi @Yinqiu, Thank you for sharing the link but that was not really helpful. I know that `MvcJsonOptions` is not compatible with .NETCore 3.1. What I would like to know that what options do I need to use to make the above code work. Thanks