# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json,

Tags: c#, json.net

I am in the process of migrating an application from dotnetcore2.0 to 3.1 and I am facing some issues with the newtonsoft dependency.

```
services.AddAuthorization()
                .AddApiExplorer()
                .AddMvcOptions(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(n =>
                {
                    n.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
                    n.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    n.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                })
                .AddDataAnnotations();
```

Comment: Could you please clarify which problems you have to solve?

Comment: When I try to debug the application, I am getting this error  "Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions'" from the module

``
BuildWebHost(args).Run();

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right the issue is caused by Swashbuckle 4 used in a .Net Core 3-Environment. What you can do to solve this is to upgrade to Swashbuckle 5. (use command install-package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore).

I found this answer here: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362757/could-not-load-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcjsonoptions-from-assembly-mi)