# Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, upgrade

This is a .NET Core 2.2 project upgraded to .NET 8.0. I am getting the error shown here. I am using the Upgrade Assistant in Visual Studio 2022. The same issue occurs if I am upgrading to .NET Core 3.2.

Application startup exception:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>
> at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.<get_Signature>g__LazyCreateSignature|21_0()
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParameters()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.ReflectionMiddlewareBinder.CreateMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.BuildApplication()

I have upgraded to nuget package

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson - 8.0.2
```

I also tried adding this code in `startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

and

```cs
services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

I am not sure why it is still looking for the .NET Core 2.2 version old nuget package and assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions`.

When I tried searching old `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions` assembly in the project folder, I found in test project in `bin\Debug\net8.0\refs` folder. I tried to delete it, but it is adding it again on build.

Comment: I suggest you could open the VS's framework to see what's the version of the .net core app you have used. It seems you didn't install the package well. Like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91ylz.png)

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362757/could-not-load-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcjsonoptions-from-assembly-mi.